# Sequence that look like a terms from a Taylor series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $u$ be a quadratic function in terms of $x$ and let $v=(\alpha-x)^2$ for some real constant $\alpha$. Let $y=\frac{u}{v}$. Given that $$v\frac{d^{n+2}y}{dx^{n+2}}+(n+2)\frac{dv}{dx}\frac{d^{n+1}y}{dx^{n+1}}+^{n+2}C_2\frac{d^{2}v}{dx^{2}}\frac{d^{n}y}{dx^{n}}=0,~n\geq 1,$$ show that the sequence $$z_n=\frac{(\alpha-x)^{n+2}}{n!}\frac{d^{n}y}{dx^{n}}$$ is an arithmetic progression.

I tried to explore by just subtracting $z_2-z_1$ as shown to get $$\frac{(\alpha-x)^{4}}{2!}\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}-\frac{(\alpha-x)^{3}}{1!}\frac{dy}{dx},$$ but even at this elementary stage I couldn't expression the above difference as a constant. Any help is appreciated.